# Probability properties and types of events

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Problem statement:

> In a group there are $4$ girls and $8$ boys. 2 persons are chosen randomly. What is the probability that:
>
> 1) they are both boys
>
> 2) there is $1$ boy and $1$ girl
>
> 3) Probability that there is at most 1 girl
>
> 4) Probability that the first is a boy and the second is a girl
>
> 5) Probability that the $2$ persons have the same sex.

For the first one I took: $A$ to be the event that the first one chosen is a boy and $B$ to be the event that the second one is also a boy. So we need to find the probability $P(A\cap B)$. We know that $P(A | B) = \frac {P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$ Then we can solve for $P(A\cap B)$ but I don't know $P(A| B)$. How should I find that?

Comment: Your events are unclear.  You say that $B$ is "the event that the second one is also a boy" But I think you mean to drop that "also".  In any case:   The probability that the first is a boy is $\frac 8{12}$. Conditioned on that, the probability that the second is also a boy is then $\frac 7{11}$.  The other problems are similar.

Comment: @lulu So for the second one it would be: the first is a boy $\frac 8{12}$ and second girl must be $\frac 4{11}$ thus the final probability would be $\frac 8{33}$ Because of the same argument?

Comment: That would be correct for the third part, not the second.  For the second you can have $BG$ or $GB$.

Comment: Another way to do the second part is to compute $P(BB)$ and $P(GG)$.  Then the probability that you have 1 boy 1 girl is $1-P(BB)-P(GG)$.  Good to do it both ways and confirm that you get the same result.

Comment: @lulu If I do the second method, for the second exercise I get $\frac {65}{132}$, but that is not correct, for $P(BB)$ I took the first answer and for $P(GG)$ I applied the same principle and got $\frac 1{12}$

Comment: What values do you get for $P(BB), P(GG)$?  $\frac 1{12}$ is obviously too low.  You already got that $P(BG)=\frac 8{33}>\frac 1{12}$.

Comment: @lulu I solved it, was a mistake, for $P(BB) = \frac {14}{33}$ and $P(GG) = \frac {1}{11}$

Answer (score 1):

Questions (1)-(4) & (5), in which order of selection doesn't matter, can be solved using a hypergeometric distribution. Let $X$ be the number of girls chosen from this group when two children are taken at random without replacement.

$$P(X = k) = \frac{{4 \choose k}{8\choose 2-k}}{{12 \choose 2}},$$
for $k = 0,1,2$ girls.

You can make a table of numerical values of a hypergeometric distribution in R by using `dhyper`
which is a hypergeometric PDF. (Ignore row numbers
in brackets [].)

```
k = 0:2;  PDF = dhyper(k, 4,8, 2)
cbind(k, PDF)
     k        PDF
[1,] 0 0.42424242    # both boys
[2,] 1 0.48484848    # one of each  # sum twp probs
[3,] 2 0.09090909                   # for (3)
```